# R Shiny - Writing helper functions that contain reactive components

Tags: r, shiny

The app below contains a `selectInput` of the English alphabet and a hidden alert with the id `letters_notif` that notifies the user if they select the letter `B`. I would like to `letters_notif` to be visible whenever the user selects `B`:

[image]

...and hidden otherwise:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

chooseLetter <- function(id, input, session = getDefaultReactiveDomain()) {

  if(input[[id]] == 'B') {

    observe(toggle(paste0(id, '_notif'), condition = input[[id]] == 'B'))

  } else input[[id]]

}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    selectInput('letters', 'Choose a letter:', LETTERS),
    hidden(tags$p(id = 'letters_notif', 'B is not allowed.'))
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {    

    observeEvent(input$letters, chooseLetter('letters', input = input))

  }
)
```

The app is working fine, but I had a question about the helper function `chooseLetter`. This function contains the portion of the server logic that checks if the `input$letters == 'B'` and returns an `observer` to toggle `letters_notif` if `input$letters == 'B'`. I'm not sure if it is advisable to extract out chunks of the server function like this - is there anything wrong with `chooseLetter` as I have defined it above?

I also don't like having to pass the `input` and `session` objects as arguments, is that bad form?

I tried using Shiny modules as an alternative but since I am trying to access inputs outside of the module, the app crashes. Here is the code that uses modules:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

chooseLetter <- function(name, input, output, session) {

  if(input[[name]] == 'B') {

    observe(toggle(paste0(name, '_notif'), condition = input[[name]] == 'B'))

  } else input[[name]]

}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    selectInput('letters', 'Choose a letter:', LETTERS),
    hidden(tags$p(id = 'letters_notif', 'B is not allowed.'))

  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {    

    observeEvent(input$letters, callModule(chooseLetter, id = 'mod', name = 'letters'))

  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a non-functional way you could write what you are doing as below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    selectInput('letters', 'Choose a letter:', LETTERS),
    hidden(tags$p(id = 'letters_notif', 'B is not allowed.'))
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {    

    observeEvent(input$letters, {

      if(input[["letters"]] == 'B') {

        observe(toggle('letters_notif', condition = input[["letters"]] == 'B'))

      } else input[["letters"]]

    })

  }
)
```

If you turn the whole `observeEvent` from above into a function then there is no need to pass `session` as an argument.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

chooseLetter <- function(id, input) {

  observeEvent(input[[id]], {

  if(input[[id]] == 'B') {

  observe(toggle(paste0(id, '_notif'), condition = input[[id]] == 'B'))

  } else input[[id]]

   })
}

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    selectInput('letters', 'Choose a letter:', LETTERS),
    hidden(tags$p(id = 'letters_notif', 'B is not allowed.'))
  ),

  server = function(input, output, session) {    

   chooseLetter(id = 'letters', input = input)

  }
)
```

This way `chooseLetters` would just be a placeholder for a "normal" `observeEvent` call. This also has the advantage that you could easily use lapply or other loops on the function to set up hidden alerts for several inputs.

Regarding passing `input` as an argument to server side function: I haven't read that it is bad style, but maybe other shiny users can chime in here.